# Spring Cron expression: 10 minutes after every hour

Tags: java, spring, cron

I am trying to configure a cron expression which runs 10 or 15 minutes after for every hour. Application has couple of cron jobs and I am trying to schedule them 15 mins apart for every hour.
After reading couple of examples I came up with these expressions:
`10 0 * * * ?` and `25 0 * * * ?`

Can you please verify them if these are correct expressions or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you've got it, the jobs only run @ 12:10am and 12:25am, respectively. Change the zeros to stars and you'll accomplish your goal of running the 2 jobs 10 and 25 minutes past every hour.

Instead of:

```
10 0 * * * ?
25 0 * * * ?
```

Use:

```
10 * * * * ?
25 * * * * ?
```

Comment: I think it's gonna work for every 10 seconds and 25 seconds. You should check it again.